# Apply Lambda on string : ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, date, lambda

I want to transform a column with string date to a other type of string date. I tried to use apply like this :

```
    self.df['mydatestring'] = self.df['mydatestring'].apply(
                             lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d/%m/%y') 
                             if pd.notnull(x) else '',
                         )
```

But i have the
`ValueError : The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.`
I don't understand why, could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `pd.to_datetime`:

```
self.df['mydatestring'] = (pd.to_datetime(self.df['mydatestring'], 
                                          format='%Y-%m-%d', 
                                          errors='coerce')
                             .dt.strftime('%d/%m/%y')
                             .fillna('')
                          )
```